# how to remove "call requires permission which may.." error in Android Studio

Tags: android, permissions, warnings, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

My code

```
private void continueCall() {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNoToCall));
        startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

Above requires whether user grant permission `CALL_PHONE` at run time which I have checked as

```
private void call() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        continueCall();
    } else {
        requestCallPermission();
    }
}
```

Still Android studio showing error **"call requires permission which may..."**

How to remove this error? Or at least suppress it.

Comment: Suppress it by clicking the yellow bulb

Comment: look here https://github.com/tananaev/traccar-client-android/issues/187

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `continueCall()` could be called from multiple places. So it isn't guaranteed to have the permission check in `call()`

So you can only suppress the error by adding:

`@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")`

Answer (score 1):

you need to put

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNoToCall));
 startActivity(callIntent);
```

inside if block

```
private void call() {
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNoToCall));
        startActivity(callIntent);
   } else {
        requestCallPermission();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `CALL_PRIVILEGED` permission:

> CALL_PRIVILEGED
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> String CALL_PRIVILEGED Allows an application to call any phone number,
>   including emergency numbers, without going through the Dialer user
>   interface for the user to confirm the call being placed.
>
> Not for use by third-party applications.
>
> Constant Value: "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"